# Vertex at high $s$ Mandelstam variable

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, collision, approximations

Previously I asked the question [Mandelstam variables high-energy limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672398/mandelstam-variables-high-energy-limit/672592#672592) in which it was said that the result $stu \approx -s^2 t$ for $s$ large was derived in the forward limit ($t \rightarrow 0$) and $s \rightarrow \infty$ (and $u/s \rightarrow -1$). I have some vertex which I want to simplify in the large $s$ limit:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{9}{4} c^2 s(u+t)^2,
\end{equation}

where $c$ is some coupling constant. I want to show that this becomes something like $-c_1 s^2 t +c_2 m^2 s^2$ for $s$ large for some constants $c_1,c_2$. But with the previously posted answer in [Mandelstam variables high-energy limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672398/mandelstam-variables-high-energy-limit/672592#672592) I couldn't succeed. I was thinking about using the formula $4m^2 = u+t+s$ but I don't see how I can get rid of the $s^3$ term when $m^2$ gets introduced.

Does someone have an idea how this limit can be recovered?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672398/

Comment: doesn't $m\rightarrow 0$ in the high energy limit?

Comment: The key was to include the $u$-channel and $t$-channel. Otherwise the result could indeed not be found... my bad